# Many "Locally New" files in Netbeans's subversion view

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7.4

I'm using Net Beans 7.4 for mac and I have a project with subversion.

On Subversion's show difference window, I get an enourmous amount of "Locally New" files. These files are not new but in the repository and running "svn status" on the command line, these files do not come up. These files also do not appear as new or modified in the file view (they have no annotation).

Having a thousand or so files in this window makes it pretty much useless. Are there any avenues that I should look at to try and fix this issue?

Comment: Same problem for Netbeans 20